Implementation of Op-Amp
I want to implement this circuit in multisim, i fail to do so, because first im not aware of the internals of this circuit, i dont understand whats the purpose of R14 and whats the purpose of VR1 and how can play with it , i dont understand how can i see what is the logic of determining the input signal to the second transistor on the right ? any help is really useful for me now
here is my "sketch" of the implementation in multisim



Fabio provides a caricature that misses out on many important details. For example, R14's wiper trims the outputs, as said. But its magnitude provides significant emitter degeneration, temperature compensation, and totally alters the gain curve, both linearizing and reducing it while also expanding the input difference range. Those aren't secondary effects, but primary. The same is true for VR1, which has DC biasing and beta compensation beyond the AC mentioned. There's a lot to discuss and I think you may need to first sit down and understand a simpler version. Start small, then expand out?

@periblepsis  Yes, agreed, R14 does indeed provide some degree of emitter degeneration, however, since its value was not mentioned I assumed its primary purpose was for offset trimming, not gain control or widening the input range (I could be wrong about that, though).  However, I did not want to mention any of those items just yet, for fear of confusing the OP.  Once the OP gets the circuit to provide some semblance of intended operation, then the importance of those issues you mentioned could - and should - be discussed.  Cheers.

Just on that issue: looking at the values of R12, R13 & R15 of the copy-paste image, it would seem that R14 is indeed not a small value.   To set the bias voltage at Q2 & Q3 collectors to be at ~half +12V would mean R14 adds between 5k to 10k to each emitter.

@FabioBarone Even a tiny value for R14 will have profound impact on the points I mentioned. And I mean tiny. (By the time 10 or 15 Ohms are on each side, it's already a whole new ballgame.) My main point, regardless, is that the OP should start with something simpler to understand.

@FabioBarone For example, here is a picture illustrating what just a few Ohms does for R14 vs behavior. The arctangent curves are without a potentiometer. The straight lines are when using a 100 Ohm pot set to 50 Ohms each side and where the BJTs are identical. I just think this isn't the circuit to get started learning on, I guess. (The 0 and 1 on the y-axis are the collector current ratios, relative to the tail value I hacked into the formula.)

@periblepsis  All true indeed.  However, the signal source the OP is using in the sim is a mere 2.5mVpk (yes, millivolts), and its frequency is a mere 1Hz - which I suspect should be 1kHz.  Anyway, I hope the OP has a go at making the improvements I mentioned; the OP may realise that, as you say, there is far more to this circuit than meets the eye.  Cheers.

@knowledge Seeker:   Please provide the link to the image you pasted; is it from a US patent, perhaps, the image seems to be in the style used for patents published during the 1960s through to the 1990s.  Or is it from a paper published in an academic journal, perhaps?  Some context for this circuit and the function it is intended to perform would be helpful.

@FabioBarone The 2N3904 came out in the summer of 1965 (Mot.) I remember seeing full page ads for it starting then. Called the 2N3903-6 series, Mot advertised them like this: *Here Are The First Low-Cost Plastic Silicon Transistors With "No Compromises" in Performance And Reliability!* They're made by the annular process. That means you get the low-leakage, long-term stability that will set your equipment performance apart from the crowd. ;)

@periblepsis  Interesting - that was a little after my time.  I grew up on the BC549/559 series, originating from Phillips, in Australia we sourced semis from Europe, the US, and Japan.   The US-sourced and in particular Motorolla semis that I saw were mainly used for RF and high power - TO-3 packages, eg: 2N3055.

@FabioBarone Just for your enjoyment, here's a scanned page from an old magazine. :) August 1965 Electronics.

@periblepsis  Nice one!  I always wondered why the BC549 series had a different pin-out to the 2N390x series (C & E swapped).   Was it a patent infringement thing?  Or just based on commercial factors, ie: not being interchangeable with a competitor product?

Knowledge Seeker - Hi, As commented above, where did the original image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to that material. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) then please add its name & link (URL) (e.g. "Datasheet XYZ" & URL). If the original source was a book or other offline material, please add a full citation e.g. title, author(s), page, edition etc. (see the linked rule for details). TY

@SamGibson infinite thanks to everyone here, ah if you are asking for the source, its from my experimental work notebook our professor gave i did some reverse image lookup on the picture myself i found a research lab in turkey is the original image source page 15: https://www.bingol.edu.tr/documents/file/A-Fak-MMF/Elektrik-Elektronik%20M%C3%BChendisli%C4%9Fi/Elektrik%20Devreleri%20Laboratuvar%C4%B1/Opampdeneyleri.pdf

@KnowledgeSeeker Start with the simpler, ideal long-tailed pair. This should not only include understanding why it functions when the bipolars are identical devices, but also understanding the impacts of the more commonly found non-idealities: typical and worst case variations in saturation current and variations in beta between pairs of discretely manufactured bipolar devices. (DC biasing, of course, must have already been mastered.) Then knowing what needs fixing for a practical discrete circuit and how can be grasped better. Where are you at with the ideal long-tailed pair?

hi @periblepsis , honestly i know the theoric background of this circuit, but my problem is how to implement/visualise the in/out signals and how to use VR1 to play with inputs

@KnowledgeSeeker The turkish text focuses on exactly that issue, lays out a table to draw picts, and asks you to perform adjustments to VR1. But before that, are you saying that you can go through all the steps needed to properly DC bias an ideal long-tailed pair, know exactly what you are doing and why, and then without error set it up with an input signal (knowing its limits) and predict its output without simulating it? Also, can you describe what happens if I cause the saturation current to be a factor of 10 different between the BJTs? Or if I vary the beta between them by a factor of 3?

@periblepsis DC bias an ideal long-tailed pair, so basically we use the (-12V / R15) to create an ideal current , and we use the (+12V/R12 & R13) to DC bias the transistor to find the Q-point, i dont honestly know what the output at the collectors would be , if anyone can make an answer i would be grateful to accept it

@KnowledgeSeeker And I don't mean this in a hand-waving qualitative way. I mean it in that you can predict quantitatively the output given a specified input difference between the bases. Not "it amplifies" but "it amplifies by exactly this much when the input difference is exactly this much."

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@KnowledgeSeeker See if you can work out a decent quiescent operating point, and add DC biasing to provide base recombination currents, for this circuit. Design from theory. Not hunt-and-peck on a Spice simulator!

@periblepsis , so i have to look for the pair $(V_{ce}, I_c)$ : since the circuit is quite symetrical i can look for the V_ce on the left-hand side, we have $V_{ce} = V_c - V_e = V_{cc} - R_1 \cdot I_c - 2R_3 \cdot \frac{I_c}{\alpha} - V_{ee}$ thus $I_c = \frac{V_{cc}- V_{ee}}{R_1 + 2\frac{R_3}{\alpha}} - \frac{V_{ce}}{R_1 + 2\frac{R_3}{\alpha}} $

@Knowledge I didn't ask for a computation based upon someone else's already existing design. This is your design. Assume a balanced Vcc and Vee such that Vcc+Vee=0. Set Vcc=10 V. Select a BJT family. Read its datasheet and select a 'good' operating Ic from it. Assume Vb1 and Vb2 are near 0 V, somehow, but need base current or else they don't work. What's the tail resistor value and why, the collector resistor values and why, and what are the value(s) of anything you use to bias the bases and how do you bias them and why? Assume no values given except Vcc and Vee. The rest is up to you.

@KnowledgeSeeker I decided to write something up for you to look at. It shows you what I was asking you to show me. But either we weren't communicating well or else you don't know how. The answer I added shows one of many possible approaches to making a design. Best wishes.

I'm just going to write up a procedure for designing a long-tailed pair, assuming all components are exactly as specified by their models and that two parts having the same model behave exactly the same as each other.
(This is never the case and it matters a lot in the case of the long-tailed pair, which is why the circuit you show is as complex as it is. But I'm not going down that rabbit hole.)
circuit topology
The circuit topology is this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
\$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ convert the collector currents of \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ into voltages. \$R_3\$ generates the required tail current to supply the quiescent collector currents for \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$. \$R_5\$ and \$R_4\$ provide the necessary recombination currents to the bases of \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$. And \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ are in a balanced arrangement which splits the tail current evenly between them, without signals applied at their bases in their quiescent state.
\$V_{_\text{CC}}\$ and \$V_{_\text{EE}}\$
Some starting point is needed for a design.
Let's set \$V_{_\text{CC}}=+10\:\text{V}\$ and \$V_{_\text{EE}}=-10\:\text{V}\$.
selecting the transistors
Let's select the DMMT3904W from Diodes, Incorporated. These are matched devices (within some limits) and are more attractive for this circuit than separate grab-bag discrete BJTs.
So that will be the BJT datasheet we'll use for design purposes.
resistor values
We will use standard resistor values from the E24 list.
working out \$I_{_{\text{C}_Q}}\$ and worst-case \$\beta\$
From this section of the datasheet:

To guarantee the best \$h_{_\text{FE}}\$ I might select \$I_{_{\text{C}_Q}}=10\:\text{mA}\$. (Note that they specify \$V_{_\text{CE}}=1\:\text{V}\$ and that's unlikely to be our quiescent case.)
However, look here:

The thermal resistance is pretty high and they specify no more than about \$200\:\text{mW}\$ if ambient is \$25^\circ\$C. But I have to figure that ambient might very well be higher than that, too.
Also, I've no interest in operating this near its maximum die temperature.
So let's select a die temperature maximum of \$90^\circ\$C and a maximum ambient temperature of \$55^\circ\$C. (Not a lot of margin!) So this leaves \$35^\circ\$C for dissipation. The thermal resistance then tells us that we can dissipate \$56\:\text{mW}\$, at most.
Well, that's in open air. I could epoxy the thing, dead-bug, onto a copper clad board to help out and lower the thermal resistance, allowing more dissipation. But we'd have to make some educated guesses about how much leeway we could get. So let's just assume open air, knowing that we could improve the situation at a later date with some experimentation and logbook results, should be want to go that far.
Maximum dissipation would occur when about \$\frac12 V_{_\text{CC}}\$ is applied across the collector-emitter -- which just happens to be about where the quiescent point (not yet determined) is likely to be.
\$56\:\text{mW}\$ at \$\frac12 V_{_\text{CC}}=5\:\text{V}\$ says \$I_{_{\text{TAIL}_Q}}=11.2\:\text{mA}\$ as our maximum tail current. This suggests \$I_{_{\text{C}_Q}}=5.6\:\text{mA}\$. While that may be slightly less than optimal for \$h_{_\text{FE}}\$, it's close.
So after reviewing the datasheet this far, we can settle on \$I_{_{\text{C}_Q}}=5.6\:\text{mA}\$ and expect \$\beta\approx 100\$, worst case (though it will likely be much better.)
Note: Whatever \$\beta\$ is, the datasheet does tell is that they are within 2% of each other. But as stated at the outset we will assume perfect matching because I still don't want to go down the rabbit hole of dealing with part differences.
\$R_5\$ and \$R_4\$
Without these, there would be no source for recombination current and the circuit would float around on leakage, variations in ambient static charges, and parasitics. Not well-managed.
If the input sources were known, it may be possible to remove them entirely or to place them in series with each base, instead, sitting between the sources and the transistor bases.
But this about DC biasing the circuit for quiescent operation and that means we cannot rely on outside circuitry to supply the recombination currents.
If these values are made larger, then the recombination currents will drop more voltage (and unpredictably, as there is quite a variation in \$\beta\$ from the datasheet.) If they are made very small, then this loads down any applied input sources with a resulting signal attenuation that may be unwanted.
So we compromise and, for now, make up a rule. Like this one:

set \$R_5\$ and \$R_4\$ such that the datasheet range for \$h_{_\text{FE}}\$ causes no more than a \$\pm5\$% change in the tail current.

That isn't the only possible rule. But it is a reasonable one. So let's go with it.
The key point is that we need to introduce some guiding principle here with a defensible reason. And the above is one-such.
Which brings us here.
establishing the tail current by specifying \$R_3\$
There isn't a specific table or chart in the datasheet that tells us what to expect for \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$ when \$I_{_{\text{C}}}=5.6\:\text{mA}\$. They do discuss the saturated value range, though:

If we use the smaller end of the range we will compute a larger value for \$R_3\$ and that's safer to use than going the other direction. Use \$V_{_{\text{BE}_Q}}=650\:\text{mV}\$ for design.
(The minimum may still be less, since these BJTs aren't quiescently operated in saturation. And the typical value is likely to be more. But I think selecting this value can be defended.)
We might just assume that node \$V_{_{\text{E}}}\$ in the schematic is exactly \$V_{_{\text{E}_Q}}=-650\:\text{mV}\$ and compute \$R_3=\frac{V_{_{\text{E}_Q}}-V_{_{\text{EE}}} }{I_{_{\text{TAIL}_Q}}}=\frac{-650\:\text{mV}-\left(-10\:\text{V}\right)}{11.2\:\text{mA}}\approx 834.8\:\Omega\$.
But that is naïve. Remember \$R_5\$ and \$R_4\$? They also drop some voltage. And, in fact, it is here that we need the above-mentioned rule:

set \$R_5\$ and \$R_4\$ such that the datasheet range for \$h_{_\text{FE}}\$ causes no more than a \$\pm5\$% change in the tail current.

The following Python/SymPy code computes the values for us:
EQ0 = Eq( 0 - (1+Pct/100)*ITailQ/2/Beta*R5 - VbeQ - (1+Pct/100)*ITailQ*R3, Vee )
for i,j in solve( [ EQ0.subs({Pct:-5,Beta:100}), EQ0.subs({Pct:+5,Beta:300}) ], [ R3, R5 ] ).items():
    i, j.subs({ VbeQ:0.65, Vee:-10, ITailQ:11.2e-3 })
(R3, 753.222341568206)
(R5, 25107.4113856069)

The standard values would be \$R_3=750\:\Omega\$ and \$R_4=R_5=24\:\text{k}\Omega\$.
(Making the base recombination current resistors a little smaller reduces the tail current variations, so that's why rounding down is better here.)
\$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$
Larger values will yield higher voltage gain. But making them too large means that the BJTs are both saturated and the resulting circuit is mostly useless. Smaller values lower the voltage gain. It's even possible to simply short out the collector resistors entirely and get no voltage gain, at all.
Here, again, we make up a rule:

The voltage drop across \$R_1\$ (or \$R_2\$, as they are the same value) should just barely avoid driving \$Q_1\$ into saturation when the full tail current is applied there.

Again, that isn't the only possible rule. In fact, saturation might even be desirable in some circumstances in order to get more voltage gain. But it is still a reasonable one. And defensible in terms of possible power dissipation in our matched BJT pair IC. So let's go with it.
We can estimate \$V_{_{\text{E}_Q}}=V_{_\text{EE}}+R_3\cdot I_{_{\text{TAIL}_Q}}=-10\:\text{V}+11.2\:\text{mA}\cdot 750\:\Omega=-1.6\:\text{V}\$. Staying out of saturation means that \$V_{_\text{CE}}\ge 1\:\text{V}\$. So \$V_{_\text{C}}\ge -600\:\text{mV}\$ and that means that the voltage drop across \$R_1\$ (or \$R_2\$) should not exceed \$V_{_\text{CC}}-V_{_\text{C}}=10\:\text{V}-\left(-600\:\text{mV}\right)=10.6\:\text{V}\$.
So we can compute \$R_1=R_2=\frac{10.6\:\text{V}}{11.2\:\text{mA}}\approx 946.43\:\Omega\$.
Using standard values this means \$R_1=R_2= 910\:\Omega\$. Or we could go with \$R_1=R_2= 1\:\text{k}\Omega\$, which may be a better choice. (See towards the end where I present arctan curves and read the discussion there.) But keep with \$R_1=R_2= 910\:\Omega\$ here.
completed schematic and predictions
Here's the completed schematic:

simulate this circuit
We estimate that \$V_{_\text{E}}\approx -1.6\:\text{V}\pm 420\:\text{mV}\$ and \$V_{_{\text{C}_1}}=V_{_{\text{C}_2}}\approx 4.9\:\text{V}\pm 510\:\text{mV}\$. Also, that \$V_{_{\text{B}_1}}=V_{_{\text{B}_2}}\approx -670\:\text{mV}\$ using \$\beta=200\$, but may be as high as \$-450\:\text{mV}\$ or as low as \$-1.3\:\text{V}\$ given the range of \$\beta\$.
Let's see what we get with LTspice using its internal 2N3904 BJT model (not necessarily based upon the same model in DMMT3904W from Diodes, Incorporated) where I've set \$\beta=200\$:

That's fairly close, despite not taking into account the Early effect (\$R_3\$'s NFB would limit the impact to about 1%) and using guessed values from the datasheet (which doesn't specify details for our exact situation.)
summary
\$r_e^{\:'}\approx 4.6\:\Omega\$ at room temp. We don't know the LTspice model's bulk emitter resistance, but I'd imagine a value of about \$300\:\text{m}\Omega\$. Adding that in and rounding to \$5\:\Omega\$ I'd expect to see a voltage gain, taken between the two collectors, of about \$\frac{910\:\Omega}{5\:\Omega}=182\$ or about \$45.2\:\text{dB}\$. LTspice reports \$45.37\:\text{dB}\$. That's better agreement than I'd expected to see.
Here are some problems:

The small signal gain is stable so long as the voltage difference between the bases is small. (Green circled area below.) But as the collector current ratio, with respect to the tail current, deviates much from 0.5 then the gain slope reduces substantially. (Red line.) This gain variation leads to significant distortion when trying to use this circuit over its fuller input range.

(Above picture taken from Abraham Pressman's "Switching and Linear Power Supply Converter Design".)
If linearity is desired (usually is not a goal here, but might be), then the input voltage difference should be limited to about \$\pm V_T\$ (the thermal voltage.)
Looking at the above chart and noting that the gain gets a lot poorer, we may have chosen larger collector resistor values. True, this would have reduced the usable magnitude of the output voltage swings. But that may be acceptable. So the rule used earlier could have been a different one. But we'd have needed to know more about the situation, too.

This circuit also doesn't do well when the common mode voltage is altered. This is because the tail current varies with the common mode voltage and that impacts the voltage gain. So the circuit doesn't reject common mode voltages well.
That can be improved greatly by replacing \$R_3\$ with a current sink. Which is a very common improvement for this topology.

The voltage gain could be a lot better. The collector resistors can be replaced by a current mirror which greatly stiffens the apparent collector loads and greatly increases the gain. However, the output becomes single-ended and effectively squirts out any difference in collector currents, where usually is found a voltage amplifier stage (VAS) with another BJT's base accepting that squirted current. And this is also a very common improvement for this topology.

Even slight differences in the temperature for the two BJTs is amplified -- a lot. So it is important that they are not only matched in behavior but also kept at the same temperature. This is why I specified the DMMT3904W device.
It's always fun to build this up on a breadboard with discrete BJTs, instead, and then simply touch one of the BJTs to warm it up a little and see how the output changes.
So putting the BJTs onto the same thermal substrate is yet another common improvement.


Once a current mirror is added as the collector load, with a VAS stage accepting the output from that mirror, and a current sink is used instead of \$R_3\$, the circuit has then become almost identical to what is actually used as the first stage in bipolar operational amplifiers. The only remaining addition is an output stage with some decent current compliance. Gain is simply huge by then and can be readily squandered in exchange for total circuit linearity and immunity to variations in operating temperature. It becomes a fantastic black box that is put to use with regularity.

Infinite thanks sir periblepsis, i will take my time into digesting this rigorous write-up

@KnowledgeS Once you get through that process and, perhaps, try out a few different ideas of your own on it, too, then you may be ready to take on some problems with respect to mismatched BJTs. The two initial mismatches will be Vbe and Beta. But another will be that the two BJTs are NOT at the same temperature during operation. All these mismatches become more obvious with more gain, too. The circuit you have makes some attempts to deal with this for a student lab built and operated by newbies. But the reasoning would more than double what I wrote above.

Nice explanation.

The purpose of R14 is to trim the outputs, OUT1 & OUT2 to be the same voltage when the input signal is zero.  This is intended to deal with real-world transistors Q1 & Q2 which are not identical; however, in a simulation, R14 should not be required because Q1 & Q2 are, in fact, identical.  So in your simulation, you won't need this.
The purpose of VR1 is to make the input signals to Q1 and Q2 different.  Looking at the image, VR1 works by connecting node B to either node A (which is the input to Q1), or to any point along the resistance between node A and node C (Gnd).  The way your sim is drawn, you now have the inputs of Q1 & Q2 both wired to the same node, the top of R1 (via R2 & R3), so in this case OUT1 & OUT2 will be the same voltage, the difference between them will be zero (or very close to zero).
To get an understanding of how this circuit works, simply split R1 into two resistors, 0.5k each connected in series, and move the connection of Q2 base resistor (R3 in your sim) to the join of these two resistors.  You should then see a difference between OUT1 & OUT2 that moves in sympathy with the input signal, V3.
